# GDB Compile/configure options for centos7

Tags: eclipse, gcc, gdb, centos7

Our codebase is triggering this bug:
https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13669

Therefore I need to compile GDB with the workaround hack, Unfortunately, I can't seem to find a list of configure options, or some kind of "enable all" flag.

I am using the CentOS 7 distro.  The gdb included is version "Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6.1-100.el7"  It seems to be installed to /usr/bin/gdb

The features I need is python pretty printing, as well as anything else eclipse might need under the hood.

This is my last attempt, but it still doesn't seem to have what i need.:
  CC=gcc ./configure --with-python=yes --with-zlib

Specifically, eclipse still can't display pretty printed values.

Also, is there any way to overwrite the package installed version so that it "inherits" the configuration?

---edit---
Also, is there a good way to turn this into a yum installable package?  Once i get this to work i need to distribute it to about 50 developer machines.

Comment: to create yum installable package I would recommend rebuilding source RPM : https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/RebuildSRPM

Answer (score 1):

FYI the issue has been fixed: https://sourceware.org/ml/gdb-patches/2017-10/msg00836.html